# es6 variable with functions and using "this"

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am learning ES6 at the moment. Just figured out a little bit about classes.
Right now I have a collection of helpers in a JSON object. How do I refer to itself? I use babel to convert it to ES5 and it doesn't like it, it makes "_this" out of "this".

```
const pixieLib = {
  methodA : (arg1) => {
    console.log('foo');
  },

  methodB : () => {
    this.methodA();
  }
};
```

If there are better ways to make helpers all suggestions are welcome when they play nice with Babel.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with `class`es. Also I think your issue is unrelated to Babel, the code just doesn't work, even when executed natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used an arrow function, which by definition closes over the this where it's created.

If you don't use, it will work normally:

```
const pixieLib = {
  methodA : function(arg1) {
    console.log('foo');
  },

  methodB : function()  {
    this.methodA();
  }
};
```

[Babel REPL test](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBADgSwB4IKYBkECMYF4YDeAUDDALapQAWIAJgIIwBcMAZgK5jBQLgAUAQwBOAcwCMASkIlSMUJBAAbVADpFIEXwDkrECC0SA3DIC-AGiIyK1OgCFmbTt15g-U6bJjUEEFdZoMbsakJkQmhkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=Node-16&version=7.14.4&externalPlugins=)

Edit:

or use ES6 Method Definitions syntax as pointed by @trincot.

```
const pixieLib = {
  methodA(arg1) {
    console.log('foo');
  },

  methodB()  {
    this.methodA();
  }
};
```

[REPL Result](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBADgSwB4IKYBkECMYF4YDeAUDDALapQAWIAJgIIAUAhgE4DmAjAJSEmkxQkEABtUAOhEh2jAOQAzECFncA3PwC-AGiL8K1OgCFGvPgJjUEEcfpoMT60hqIbVQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=Node-16&version=7.14.4&externalPlugins=)

Comment: @trincot you're right, i'll edit.